# Storing json data in database and format of json object

Tags: javascript, json

This is my Json object for products which is stored in database. This json object is also storing another json object with images.
1.question: Is this the correct way of storing data about products in database or should be images stored separately?
2.question: Is format of this json object correct, i'm especially interested in sub json "images"?
3.question: How should JSON object look like if sub Json "images" would have like some json index array, where index would be the position of image

```
{
  "id_product": "1000",
  "name": "Rippin Unions",
  "description": "Vel aut sed neque enim illum mollitia. Molestias aperiam qui dolorem qui est. Dolore cumque dolore formatedtempore ipsum. Veniam molestiae laudantium voluptates numquam.",
  "date_c": "2015-12-31 02:06:32",
  "date_u": null,
  "id_category": "46",
  "id_user": "123",
  "alias": "rippin-unions",
  "active": "1",
  "images": "[
              {thumbImage:"http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?27403",image:"http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?28526",position:4},
              {thumbImage:"http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?25207",image:"http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?73566",position:1},
              {thumbImage:"http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?26960",image:"http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?72686",position:0},
              {thumbImage:"http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?25168",image:"http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?22297",position:2},
              {thumbImage:"http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?94897",image:"http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?94418",position:3}
             ]"
   }
```

I'm askin this because currently i have problems printing JSON data.
All i can do is call `products[0].images`, but if i try to select first thumb picture i fail. i Have tried many variations and nothing is working
If you need any additional question, please let me know and i will provide.

Thanks in advance

Comment: JSON supports arrays, so why don't you store images as an actual array: `"images": [{thumbImage: "..."}, ...]`. Then you can access the first image with `products[0].images[0]`.

Comment: because i'm new with JS and i'm searching for examples and good practices

Comment: If you google "json example", the first result already answers your question. Being new is no excuse.

Comment: dude, belive me i have searched everything, but sometimes you either don't know what you are searching and if this is the right way, like you said that json array looks like this. So please don't down vote and let the good people of stackoverflow help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend giving this article a read from [tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-json--active-8817)

Copy and past the following at [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate,

```
 {
    "id_product": 1000,
    "name": "Rippin Unions",
    "description": "Vel aut sed neque enim illum mollitia. Molestias aperiam qui dolorem qui est. Dolore cumque dolore formatedtempore ipsum. Veniam molestiae laudantium voluptates numquam.",
    "date_c": "2015-12-31 02:06:32",
    "date_u": null,
    "id_category": 46,
    "id_user": 123,
    "alias": "rippin-unions",
    "active": 1,
    "images": [{
        "thumbImage": "http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?27403",
        "image": "http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?28526",
        "position": 4
    }, {
        "thumbImage": "http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?25207",
        "image": "http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?73566",
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "thumbImage": "http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?26960",
        "image": "http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?72686",
        "position": 0
    }, {
        "thumbImage": "http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?25168",
        "image": "http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?22297",
        "position": 2
    }, {
        "thumbImage": "http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?94897",
        "image": "http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?94418",
        "position": 3
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON seems to be invalid, when you want to test your json structure sites like [this](http://jsonlint.com/) are very helpful.

edit: In your case a valid JSON would be:

`{
    "id_product": "1000",
    "name": "Rippin Unions",
    "description": "Vel aut sed neque enim illum mollitia. Molestias aperiam qui dolorem qui est. Dolore cumque dolore formatedtempore ipsum. Veniam molestiae laudantium voluptates numquam.",
    "date_c": "2015-12-31 02:06:32",
    "date_u": "null",
    "id_category": "46",
    "id_user": "123",
    "alias": "rippin-unions",
    "active": "1",
    "images": "[{'thumbImage': 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?27403\','image':      'http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?28526\','position': '4'},{'thumbImage': 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?25207\','image':'http: //lorempixel.com/1024/768/?73566\','position':'1'}]"
}`

Comment: it looks like yes, but i'm searching how valid one should look like. thx for effort and link any way